# Is there a way to write code that a program can accept any text file regardless of the layout structure?

Tags: python, text-files, dfa

I’m wondering if there’s a way to write code where it accepts any DFA text file that outputs all the states, number of states, alphabet size, alphabet symbols, the transitions involved, the start state, the number of final start states and the final regardless if the layout/process is done differently

```
This is my current code:
#User enters text file names
user_input = input("Enter First DFA Text file: ")
user_input2 = input("Enter Second DFA Text file: ")

#Opens the inputted text files
dfaFile = open(user_input, "r")
DFA1 = dfaFile.read().splitlines()

dfaFile2 = open(user_input2, "r")
DFA2 = dfaFile2.read().splitlines()

Lines = dfaFile.readlines()
Lines2 = dfaFile2.read().splitlines()

#Construction Method #1: Getting the states for DFA "N"
DFA_N_States = set()
for r in DFA1[1].split(): 
    for s in DFA2[1].split(): 
        DFA_N_States.add(r + s) 
print(DFA_N_States)

#Construction Method #2: Getting the transitions between each state in DFA "N"
t1 = {
(DFA1[1].split()[0], DFA1[3].split()[0]): DFA1[4].split()[0], 
(DFA1[1].split()[0], DFA1[3].split()[1]): DFA1[4].split()[1],
(DFA1[1].split()[1], DFA1[3].split()[0]): DFA1[4].split()[1],
(DFA1[1].split()[1], DFA1[3].split()[1]): DFA1[4].split()[0],
}

t2 = {
(DFA2[1].split()[1], DFA2[3].split()[0]): DFA2[4].split()[0],
(DFA2[1].split()[1], DFA2[3].split()[1]): DFA2[4].split()[0],
(DFA2[1].split()[1], DFA2[3].split()[1]): DFA2[4].split()[0],
(DFA2[1].split()[2], DFA2[3].split()[0]): DFA2[4].split()[1],
(DFA2[1].split()[2], DFA2[3].split()[1]): DFA2[4].split()[0],
}

t3 = dict()

for r in DFA1[1].split()[0], DFA1[1].split()[1]:

    for s in DFA2[1].split()[1], DFA2[1].split()[2]:

        for c in [DFA1[3].split()[0], DFA1[3].split()[1], DFA2[3].split()[0], DFA2[3].split()[1]]:

            t3[(r + s, c)] = t1[(r, c)] + t2[(s, c)]
            #
print(t3)

#Construction Method #3: Getting the Start State of DFA "N"
DFAN_StartState = set()
for DFA1_StartState in DFA1[6].split():
    for DFA2_StartState in DFA2[7].split():
        DFAN_StartState.add(DFA1_StartState + DFA2_StartState)
print(DFAN_StartState)
```

This implemented code has been made that it accepts these two text file structures.

**DFA1 Text File:**

```
2 #Number of DFA states - line index[0]
A B #DFA States - line index[1], A[split index 0], B[split index 1]
2 #Alphabet size - line index[2]
a b #alphabet symbols - line index [3] , symbol "a"[split index 0], symbol "b"[split index 1]
B A #Transition - line index [4], B[split index 0] & A[split index 1]
A B #Transition - line index [5], A[split index 0] & B[split index 2] 
A #DFA Start State - line index [6]
1 #Number of Final DFA States - line index [7]
A #DFA Final State - line index [8]
```

**DFA2 Text File:**

```
3 #Number of DFA states - line index[0]
x y z #DFA states - line index[1] x[split index 0], y[split index 1], z[split index 2]
2 #Alphabet size - line index [3]
a b #alphabet symbols - line index [4] symbol "a" [split line index 0]. b[split line index 1]
z y # Transition - line index [5], z[split index 0] & y[split index 1]
z z # Transition - line index [6], z[split index 0] & z[split index 1]
y z # Transition - line index [7], y[split index 0] & z[split index 1]
x # DFA Start State - line index [8]
2 # Number of DFA Final States - line index [9]
x y # DFA Final States - line index [10]
```

The output for these two text files is:

```
{'Ax', 'By', 'Az', 'Bx', 'Bz', 'Ay'}
{('Ay', 'a'): 'Bz', ('Ay', 'b'): 'Az', ('Az', 'a'): 'By', ('Az', 'b'): 'Az', ('By', 'a'): 'Az', ('By', 'b'): 'Bz', ('Bz', 'a'): 'Ay', ('Bz', 'b'): 'Bz'}
{'Ax'}
```

What I wanna know is how can I write a program that can take any text file and do the same thing that’s happened to these two text files despite the structure being different. For example, I have these two text files I want to pair:

**DFA Example Text File 1:**

```
6 - #Number of states, line index [0]
1 2 3 4 5 6 - #States, line index [1], 1 [split index 0], 2[split index 1], 3[split index 2], 4[split index 3], 5[split index 4], 6[split index 5]
2 – Alphabet, Line index [2] 
a b #alphabet symbols - line index [3] symbol "a" [split line index 0]. b[split line index 1]
3 2 – # Transition - line index [4], 3[split index 0] & 2[split index 1]
4 2 – # Transition - line index [5], 4[split index 0] & 2[split index 1]
5 4 – # Transition - line index [6], 5[split index 0] & 4[split index 1]
5 4 – # Transition - line index [7], 5[split index 0] & 4[split index 1]
6 6 – # Transition - line index [8], 6[split index 0] & 6[split index 1]
6 6 – # Transition - line index [9], 5[split index 0] & 4[split index 1]
1 – Start State, Line index [10]
1 – Number of Final states, Line index [11]
5 – Final state, Line index[12]
```

**DFA Example Text File 2:**

```
4 – #Number of states, line index [0]
1 2 3 4 – - #States, line index [1], 1 [split index 0], 2[split index 1], 3[split index 2], 4[split index 3],
2 – Alphabet, Line index [2] 
a b #alphabet symbols - line index [3] symbol "a" [split line index 0]. b[split line index 1]
2 1 – # Transition - line index [4], 2[split index 0] & 1[split index 1]
3 2 – # Transition - line index [5], 3[split index 0] & 2[split index 1]
4 4 –  # Transition - line index [6], 4[split index 0] & 4[split index 1]
4 4 – # Transition - line index [7], 4[split index 0] & 4[split index 1]
1 – Start State, Line index [8]
1 – Number of final states, Index [9]
3 – Final State [Index 10]
```

Is there a possible way to have my code written that it takes any two text files and still output the same way successfully like with my DFA1 and DFA2 text files despite the structures being different? Thoughts/Advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you're describing is why folks have invented structured, nestable data formats like XML and JSON. Assigning a scope to repeated segments lets you have more or fewer of them. Another solution is to have each line identify itself with some string so that it can only mean one thing. For scoping, consider defining your files in JSON, YAML, etc. For identifiers, consider prepending a character to each line to tell your system what the line represents, such as `T 2 1` for a transition from `2` to `1`, `A a b` to say your alphabet is `a` and `b`, etc.

Comment: Now, if your data format is not changeable, I would suggest logic that reads every two-item line from index 4 on as a transition, and the first one-item line after that as the start state, then number of final states, then the final states. This is similar to using identifiers for line types, but instead you're using the structure of the lines to help determine what it is.